# Using python (acora) to find lines containing keywords

Tags: python, search, aho-corasick

I'm writing a program that reads in a directory of text files and finds a specific combination of strings that are overlapping (i.e. shared among all files). My current approach is to take one file from this directory, parse it, build a list of every string combo, and then search for this string combo in the other files. For instance, if I'd ten files, I'd read one file, parse it, store the keywords I need, then search the other nine files for this combination. I'd repeat this for every file (making sure that the single file doesn't search itself). To do this, I'm trying to use python's [acora](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/acora/) module.

The code I've thus far is:

```
def match_lines(f, *keywords):
    """Taken from [https://pypi.python.org/pypi/acora/], FAQs and Recipes #3."""
    builder = AcoraBuilder('\r', '\n', *keywords)
    ac = builder.build()

    line_start = 0
    matches = False
    for kw, pos in ac.filefind(f):  # Modified from original function; search a file, not a string.
        if kw in '\r\n':
            if matches:
                yield f[line_start:pos]
                matches = False
            line_start = pos + 1
        else:
            matches = True
    if matches:
        yield f[line_start:]


def find_overlaps(f_in, fl_in, f_out):
    """f_in: input file to extract string combo from & use to search other files.
    fl_in: list of other files to search against.
    f_out: output file that'll have all lines and file names that contain the matching string combo from f_in.
    """
    string_list = build_list(f_in)  # Open the first file, read each line & build a list of tuples (string #1, string #2). The "build_list" function isn't shown in my pasted code.
    found_lines = []  # Create a list to hold all the lines (and file names, from fl_in) that are found to have the matching (string #1, string #2).
    for keywords in string_list:  # For each tuple (string #1, string #2) in the list of tuples
        for f in fl_in:  # For each file in the input file list
            for line in match_lines(f, *keywords):
                found_lines.append(line)
```

As you can probably tell, I used the function `match_lines` from the acora web page, "FAQ and recipes" #3. I also used it in the mode to parse files (using `ac.filefind()`), also located from the web page.

The code seems to work, but it's only yielding me the file name that has the matching string combination. My desired output is to write out the entire line from the other files that contain my matching string combination (tuple).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not seeing what here would produce filenames, as you say it does.

Regardless, to get line numbers, you just need to count them as you pass them in match_lines():

```
line_start = 0
line_number = 0
matches = False
text = open(f, 'r').read()
for kw, pos in ac.filefind(f):  # Modified from original function; search a file, not a string.
    if kw in '\r\n':
        if matches:
            yield line_number, text[line_start:pos]
            matches = False
        line_start = pos + 1
        line_number += 1
    else:
        matches = True
if matches:
    line_number, yield text[line_start:]
```

Comment: "I'm not seeing what here would produce filenames, as you say it does.": apparently you're right. I tested my original code again on two files that I know had the matching strings, and only one of them was returned as a file name. Apparently the code to even `yield` the file name with a match isn't working. Do you know how to fix this part (because I can't even test the `line_number` matching if python doesn't even find the right files that have the strings I'm looking for).

Comment: I don't see any code which might even theoretically yield a filename. I only see code that it can yield the contents of a matching line: yield f[line_start:pos]

Comment: Sorry for the late reply; I went out of town. My problem is that even the `yield f[line_start:pos]` isn't working; I'm not getting the full line of the file that contains my matching keywords.

Comment: What ARE you getting?

Comment: I'm just getting the full path of the file, which is `f`. In other words, `yield` is giving me `f`.

Comment: Oh. I assumed f was the contents of a file. If f is just the filename, this can't possibly work, yeah. Looking at how 'filefind' works I understand it better now. You need to actually read the file to be able to return parts of its contents, I'll update my answer.

Comment: If the updated answer solved your problem, can you click the checkmark to accept it? Thanks!